# pandas calculating mean per month

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I created the following dataframe:

```
availability = pd.DataFrame(propertyAvailableData).set_index("createdat")

monthly_availability = availability.fillna(value=0).groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'))
```

This gives the following output

```
            2015-08-18  2015-09-09  2015-09-10  2015-09-11  2015-09-12  \
createdat                                                                
2015-08-12         1.0         1.0         1.0         1.0         1.0   
2015-08-17         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
2015-08-18         0.0         1.0         1.0         1.0         1.0   
2015-08-18         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
2015-08-19         0.0         1.0         1.0         1.0         1.0   
2015-09-03         0.0         1.0         1.0         1.0         1.0   
2015-09-03         0.0         1.0         1.0         1.0         1.0   
2015-09-07         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
2015-09-08         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
2015-09-11         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
```

I'm trying to get the averages per created at month by doing:

```
monthly_availability_mean = monthly_availability.mean()
```

However, here I get the following output:

```
            2015-08-18  2015-09-09  2015-09-10  2015-09-11  2015-09-12  \
createdat                                                                
2015-08-31    0.111111    0.444444    0.666667    0.777778    0.777778   
2015-09-30    0.000000    0.222222    0.222222    0.222222    0.222222   
2015-10-31    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

And when I hand check august I get:

```
1.0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 / 5 = 0.2
```

---

How do I get the correct mean per month?

Comment: Hmmm, for me it works nice. Maybe index is not sorted and there are another rows - try `df = df.sort_index()`

Comment: thanks! I tried:

    `availability = pd.DataFrame(propertyAvailableData).set_index("createdat")`
    `availability = availability.sort_index()`
    `monthly_availability = availability.fillna(value=0).groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'))`

but still get the same results

Comment: I think you need `sort_index` for better checking data, because it seems there areanother rows with August index. Or problem is also with your short sample?

Comment: Thanks I double checked the data and it seems there were indeed more samples, so that's solved. Last question I'm wondering about is why head doesn't show the right sorting?

Comment: Hmmm, head show only first `5` rows, so by default there is no sorting.

Comment: Thanks, for the help it's a lot more clear now

Comment: Sure, no problem. Nice day!

Answer (score 4):

```
availability.resample('M').mean()
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue and solved it with the following code

```
#load data daily
df = pd.read_csv('./name.csv')
#set Date as index
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df_date = df.set_index('Date', inplace=False)
#get monthly mean
df_month = df_date.resample('M').mean()
#group months
df_monthly_mean = df_month.groupby(df_daily.index.month).mean()
```

How that this was helpful!