# How to apply avg function to DataFrame series monthly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame series with day resolution. I want to transform the series to a series of monthly averages. Ofcourse I can apply rolling mean and select only every  30th of means but it would not precise. I want to get series which contains mean value from the previous month on every first day of a month. For example, on February 1 I want to have daily average for the January. How can I do this in pythonic way?

Comment: Can you provide a **[mcve]**?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388707/pandas-calculating-mean-per-month

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030171/how-get-monthly-mean-in-pandas-using-groupby

Comment: Thank you, Rahul!

Answer (score 0):

data.resample('M', how='mean')